# MongoDB, How to give 'undefined' in java driver? (null didn't work)

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Consider the follow the sample aggregate query to find if a field exists or not:

```
db.coll.aggregate({"$project":{"exists":{ "$cond" : [ {"$eq": ["$fieldName", undefined] } , "true" ,  "false" ]}}})
```

This aggregate works as expected in mongo shell. But using null in the place of undefined didn't work in mongo shell(**why?**), as below:

```
db.coll.aggregate({"$project":{"exists":{ "$cond" : [ {"$eq": ["$fieldName", null] } , "true" ,  "false" ]}}})
```

I want to use this operation through java driver.
But I dont know how to convert this to java driver as it doesn't have `undefined`. Using `null` in the place of undefined didn't work in java too..

Why is it designed this way?

Comment: Is there a reason you're no using the `$exists` operator ? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/
You may also want to check out: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-query-for-nulls

Comment: What do you plan to do with resultant field?  There may be other ways to get there.

Comment: I want to set another field based on this field's value. For instance, if this field has 'A' then set 'type' field as type1, else if 'B' then set as 'type2' else if field doesnt exists set as 'type3'.